# Did Emoji Break My JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, emoji

It appears that a user entering emoji into an HTML `<textarea>` is causing the closing JSON `}` to be lost somewhere on the line when transferred to a server using a jquery ajax form (and a multipart form post).

Has anyone ever seen something like this happen, or have some other explanation that might cause the effect? (We have been testing thousands of objects and this is the first one to fail)

**Edit 1: The indentation of the JSON was created by JSON.stringify implying it was a valid JSON object when created.**

**Edit 2: Here is the JSON object, and stringified version in question, it appears as though the loss may appear on it's way to S3 via Knox/NodeJS.**

**Edit 3: Original characters entered:** `ðŸ˜œ`

```
object
{ url: 'foobarurl',
  uqid: 'foobaruqid',
  message_id: '9005789165956076.4317795615643263',
  author: 'guest',
  created: 1410088784916,
  message: 'Ã°Å¸ËœÅ“' }

stringified
{
  "url": "foobarurl",
  "uqid": "foobaruqid",
  "message_id": "9005789165956076.4317795615643263",
  "author": "guest",
  "created": 1410088784916,
  "message": "Ã°Å¸ËœÅ“"
}
```

[image: Bad file on the left, good file on the right.]

Comment: Very probable. I'd advice encoding any user input strings before adding to JSON or any other kind of submission to the server.

Comment: can you post data passed thru JSON.stringify ?

Comment: May this help you: https://gist.github.com/dougalcampbell/2024272 ?

Comment: It looks like it's definitely an encoding issue, and the only answer is to encodeURIComponent decodeURIComponent the message before and after presenting it.

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian I wouldn't.  The JSON stringifying should be taking care of this problem, and in this case I suspect that the problem is somewhere else down the line.

Comment: @Brad But stringify doesn't encode anything, though, and definitely doesn't handle the double quotemark in the emoji string: "Ã°Å¸ËœÅ“"

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian It's just UTF-8 which is valid in JSON.  There is nothing to handle.  The problem isn't with the stringifying... something is happening to this JSON in transit or prior to the deserializing.

Comment: It's happening somewhere in Knox (S3 api).

Comment: Many years later, since there are no answers on this post. I seem to have run into a similar issue where the hourglass-emoji ( ⏳ ) has broken my json from a get-request. Did you ever figure out a way around it?